# Expected time to type a certain sequence

Tags: probability

I have a simplified version of the monkey typing ABRACADABRA problem and my approach to it does not yield the correct answer but I haven't been able to spot the error in my reasoning.

The problem is as follows. There is a typewriter with three characters on it, namely A, B and C. There is also a monkey hitting a key on the typewriter randomly such that after $n$ hits, the resulting sequence is $X_1X_2\ldots X_n$ where $(X_i)_i$ is an iid sequence with $P\{X_1 = A\} = P\{X_1 = B\} = P\{X_1 = C\} = 1/3$. Let $T$ be the random time (in this case also a stopping time) the sequence ABC first appears once the monkey starts typing. What is the expected value of $T$?

My approach was based on conditioning the expectation of $T$ on the first hits as follows.
\begin{align}
E[T] &= E[T\mid A]\frac{1}{3} + \underbrace{E[T\mid B]}_{E[T] + 1}\frac{1}{3} + \underbrace{E[T\mid C]}_{E[T] + 1}\frac{1}{3} \\
E[T\mid A] &= \underbrace{E[T\mid AA]}_{E[T\mid A] + 1}\frac{1}{3} + E[T\mid AB]\frac{1}{3} + \underbrace{E[T\mid AC]}_{E[T] + 2}\frac{1}{3} \\
E[T\mid AB] &= \underbrace{E[T\mid ABA]}_{E[T\mid A] + 2}\frac{1}{3} + \underbrace{E[T\mid ABB]}_{E[T] + 3}\frac{1}{3} + \underbrace{E[T\mid ABC]}_{3}\frac{1}{3} \\
\end{align}

Here I can solve for $E[T],E[T\mid A],E[T\mid AB]$ but I get $E[T] = 3$, which I know is not the right answer. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: I can not answer your question, but I know if you flip a fair coin the expected time for the first time getting ABA is 10. you can find a reference in Levin Peres Wilmers in mixing times for markov chains..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My set up is quite similar to yours, but I get an expected value of $27$, which I believe is correct (by calculating it a different way).

Let $E$ be the expected number of steps until ABC appears.
Let $E_A$ be the expected number of steps after an A, and $E_{AB}$ be the expected number of steps after an AB.

Then, on the first step, either an A appears (probability 1/3) or it doesn't (probability 2/3).  If it doesn't, then we've take one step, and are back where we started, so
$$
E = \frac{1}{3}(1+E_A) + \frac{2}{3}(1+E).
$$
If the current step was an A, then one of three things happens: we type a B, an A, or neither, each with 1/3 probability.  Hence:
$$
E_A = \frac{1}{3}(1+E_{AB}) + \frac{1}{3}(1+E_A) + \frac{1}{3}(1+E).
$$
If we've reached the AB state, then one of three things happens: we type a C (and we're done), we type an A, or neither, each with probability 1/3.  Hence:
$$
E_{AB} = \frac{1}{3}(1) + \frac{1}{3}(1+E_A) + \frac{1}{3}(1+E)
$$
where $E$ is the expected number of steps until $ABC$, $E_A$ is the expected number of steps following an $A$, and $E_{AB}$ is the expected number of steps following $AB$.

Solving this system, I find $E=27$.

In your system, you have some expressions like $E(T)+2$ and $E(T)+3$ which should be $E(T)+1$, since you have already counted the other steps by earlier $E(T)+1$ expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you perhaps explain the three equations you wrote?

Comment: Added.  Let me know if you need more clarification. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I am mostly puzzled on why you add +1 to the terms on the right.

Comment: The plus one is to account for the current step.  For the first equation, if the first step is an A, then the expected number of steps is 1 (the step that gave an A) plus the expected number of steps after an A.  Likewise, if the first step is a B or C, then the expected number of steps is 1 (the step that gave a B or a C) plus the expected number of steps generally, E, since a B or C means we start over, *after using up one step*.

Comment: Further example: in the third equation, notice that, after getting to AB, we have at least one more step to take.  One-third of the time, it's a C and so we add one more step and we're done.  If it's an A, then we account for that step, and then add the expected number of steps after an A. Etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but here is my reasoning, which leads to a different equation than yours. For any finite partitioning of the probability space, $(A_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$, and a random variable $X$ defined on that space you can write 
$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1,\ldots,n}E[X\mid A_i] P(A_i)$$
So applying this formula into our case gives
$$E = \frac{1}{3}E_A + \frac{1}{3}E_B + \frac{1}{3}E_C$$
We then say $E_B = E_C = E + 1$. But I don't see why we add $1$ to $E_A$.

Comment: Two things.  One: my $E_A$ is the expected number of steps *after* throwing an A, not the expected number of steps starting with an A.  Second, solving your system I find $E(T)=27$, not $3$, so you appear to have just made an algebraic error somewhere.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved it again and got $27$ this time.

Comment: Great! It seems that you and I did exactly the same thing with just slightly different variables.